# locally compact, and compact neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology, compactness

We know that $Y =  X \cup \{‎\infty\}$ is not $T_2$ unless $X$ is itself $T_2$ and locally compact.( Y is one point compatification)

> if  $X$ is a **locally compact** space, will **the set of compact neighborhoods of each point is a local base**?

Comment: There are several different definitions of [local compactness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space), and if $X$ is not $T_2$, they do not coincide; which one are you using.

Comment: A space $X$ is called local compact if every $x \in X$ has a compact  neighborhoods.Is the above theorem right according this definition?

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $0 \in \Bbb{Q} \subset \Bbb{Q} \cup \{\infty\}$ with the one-point compactification topology. Then $\Bbb{Q}$ is open but contains no compact neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: A space $X$  is called local compact if every $x∈X$  has a compact neighborhoods.Is the above theorem right according this definition

Comment: @fatemeh That is the definition I use in the answer. Is there a problem with the counterexample?

Comment: Which one of definition can we use to the theorem is right?

Comment: That the compact neighborhoods form a base is one of the definitions.